# Desktop environment in Linux which prevents applications from stealing focus

Tags: linux, desktop-environment

I would like to ask if there is a **DE** in **Linux** which **prevents** applications being in the opening state from **stealing** the **focus** from the current one, through an option.

Stealing focus is very annoying!

Tia

Comment: Can you be a little more clear on "stealing focus" ?  Using Mint+MATE, I launch an app and while its window is "on top" of this one, my wheelie mouse scroll and keyboard are still focused on this window.  Or are you looking to have the newly launched app start "behind" or "under" the current window?

Comment: @ivanivan: The second one: "The newly launched app start "behind" or "under" the current window." Even if, an input is required, for example a password, this should still open "behind" or "under" the current window. Any "activity" should only be displayed in the panel. Tia